# CA2202 Do not dispose objects multiple times - many times in managed c++

Tags: c++, code-analysis, managed-c++

We are getting many instances of: "CA2202   Do not dispose objects multiple times" in managed c++ with code analysis on.

To me it seems like a mistake in the code analysis, but I may be missing something.

CA2202  Do not dispose objects multiple times   Object 'gcnew ConfigurationDataAssembler()' can be disposed more than once in method 'DataAssembler::CreateConfiguration(Guid, int^, int^, ObjectReference^, ObjectReference^, ObjectReference^, List^%, PLResult^%)'. To avoid generating a System.ObjectDisposedException you should not call Dispose more than one time on an object.: Lines: 935, 938   PL  dataassembler.cpp   935

The two lines it mentions are "return nullptr" and "return configDTO"

I have marked those lines with comments // here, // and here

Here is the function

```
  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // For IDataAssembler
  Ivara::PL::Data::UIData::Control::MCLBConfig^ DataAssembler::CreateConfiguration( System::Guid activityKey, int subscriptionID, int controlID, ObjectReference^ pRootObjRef, ObjectReference^ pSelectedObjRef, ObjectReference^ pOwningObjRef, [Out] List<Ivara::PL::Data::UIData::Control::ConfigurationListItem^>^% configList, [Out] PLResult^% result )
  {
     try
     {
        AutoStopWatch stopwatch( __FUNCTION__, LogCategories::RemotingTimings );
        ThreadToActivity cTTA( activityKey );

        result = PLResult::Success;

        //param check
        if ( subscriptionID <= 0 )
        {
           throw gcnew Ivara::PL::Exceptions::IvaraArgumentException( _T( "Invalid configurationID" ), _T( "configurationID" ) );
        }

        //fetch config
        UserConfigurationOR orUserConfig( subscriptionID );


        if ( !orUserConfig.isSet() )
        {
           result = gcnew PLResult( PLResult::eStatus::RelatedObjectNotFound, String::Format( _T( "The user configuration {0} could not be found" ), subscriptionID ) );
           return nullptr;
        }

        UserConfiguration* pUserConfig = orUserConfig.qryObjPtr();
        if ( pUserConfig == NULL )
        {
           result = gcnew PLResult( PLResult::eStatus::RelatedObjectNotFound, String::Format( _T( "The user configuration {0} could not be fetched, even though isSet returns true" ), subscriptionID ) );
           return nullptr;
        }
        //create assembler 
        ConfigurationDataAssembler assembler;
        assembler.Initialize( controlID, pRootObjRef, pSelectedObjRef, pOwningObjRef, result );
        if ( result != PLResult::Success )
        {
           return nullptr; // here
        }
        Ivara::PL::Data::UIData::Control::MCLBConfig^ configDTO = assembler.AssembleConfigurationDTO( pUserConfig, configList /*out param*/, nullptr );
        return configDTO; // and here

     }
     catch ( OTBaseException& unmanagedException )
     {
        throw FatalExceptionPolicy::HandleUnmanagedException( &unmanagedException, __FUNCDNAME__, __FILE__, __LINE__ );
     }
     catch ( Exception^ managedException )
     {
        throw FatalExceptionPolicy::HandleManagedException( managedException, __FUNCDNAME__, __FILE__, __LINE__ );
     }
  }
```

Comment: Is this your actual code? The signature doesn't match and I don't see `gcnew ConfigurationDataAssembler` or any `Dispose`.

Comment: This is the actual code.  I'm pretty sure it is talking about the object constructed in the line: "ConfigurationDataAssembler assembler;"